# Comparison count() not giving correct results

Tags: ruby, comparison

I'm trying to count items in an array by comparing to objects in a 2d array but the outcome is incorrect and I can't see why. The only reason I can see is that it's comparing addresses rather than values.

```
#@rules[0][0] contains 1
#@items contains [1,1]
@items = [1,1]
@rules = Array.new() {Array.new}
@rules.push([])
@rules[0].push(1)
actualFreq = @items.count(@rules[0][0])
puts actualFreq # should be 2 but outcome is 0
```

Comment: Please post runnable code that reproduces the problem

Comment: Do you still need the runnable code?

Comment: Um, yeah. I thought I got it, but then realized I was wrong. So yes, please post it.

Comment: It is almost sure that @items is not [1,1] OR @rules[0][0] is not 1.

Comment: It works perfectly for me: `@items.count(@rules[0][0]) #=> 2`

Comment: @halfelf I've printed them out, and yes they are. Unless they're not of the same type, but won't that throw up an error?

Comment: @MichaelKohl Well that isn't exactly how I've assigned values to items and rules in my code. Maybe the problem is there..

Comment: @Neeta: your updated code prints 2 for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by using:

```
num = @rules[0][0]
actualFreq = @items.count(num[0])
puts actualFreq
```